# GMT-0400 and GMT-0500 shift

Tags: javascript, python, json

Why does GMT-0400 shift to GMT-0500 pre 1989?

```
> new Date('1989-04-02T23:01:14.52Z')
Sun Apr 02 1989 19:01:14 GMT-0400 (EDT)
> new Date('1988-04-02T23:01:14.52Z')
Sat Apr 02 1988 18:01:14 GMT-0500 (EDT)
```

Does it have something to do with daylight savings time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From 1987 until 2007, daylight saving time started on the first Sunday in April.  So in 1988, that was on April 3rd, and in 1989 April 2nd.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_time_in_the_United_States#DST_1966